# UIPickerView animation glitch

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uipickerview, uianimation

I have a problem with an effect I am trying to implement where a UIPickerView slides up when a button is pressed.

```
   -(IBAction)slideUp:(id)sender{
if([sender currentTitle] == @"Select"){

[pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 415.0, 320.0, 216.0)];
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 201.0, 320.0, 216.0)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[slideButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}
}

As you can see, the code first checks if the button's title is "Select" or "Done", and if it is select it slides in the UIPickerView. However, every time I build the application, the first time you press the button, the UIPickerView immediately appears in the end position, and then slides out of view. The button title does not change. After this initial glitch, it works fine.

If you know why this might be happening, or can think of a quick fix for it, I would really appreciate it.

Luke

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are getting this glitch, but there are a few things I would do differently in your code. First, I would set the initial frame of the picker view, somewhere far away, in some other method (possibly right after you create it). Then I would just reference its initial frame before the animation block to a new CGRect struct, which I will animate and reassign. Second, if you just want to animate the y-component of the picker view, then I would also specify that in the animation.

Here's my changes in your code:

```
-(IBAction)slideUp:(id)sender {

if([sender currentTitle] == @"Select") {

CGRect pickerFrame = pickerView.frame;   // You set pickerView.frame in some other method.

[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

pickerFrame.origin.y = 201.0f;
pickerView.frame = pickerFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];

[slideButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Tell me if this is any good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I implemented your code and the same thing happened. Maybe it's just the iOS simulator, and when I provision my iPhone it'll work, because I can't think of why either way would cause this glitch.

Comment: I have a similar animation running in my app without any problems whatsoever. I actually ran the code above and the animation is glitch-free (I didn't use a PickerView though, just a simple UIView). I really have no idea why this happening to you, then. If you ever find out why, check back with me, I'd very much like to know.